# Youtube API. Поиск видео

Tags: youtube-api

Всем привет! 
 
Через API выполняю поиск, но в большинстве случаев есть разница в ответе API и при поиске того же запроса напрямую в youtube. Конкретно в моей ситуации - на сайте по запросу "racing" третье видео это "Drag Racing THRILLS and SPILLS - Carnage Fest", но API с идентичными параметрами его не выдает. Пробовал со всеми типами сортировки (по умолчанию "по релевантности"), по времени и по типу.

Запрос:

```
$youtube->search->listSearch('id, snippet', [
   'q' => 'racing',
   'maxResults' => 6];
```

Comment: При поиске через сайт он учитывает просмотренные видео. Попробуйте под vpn посмотреть с другого браузера, убедитесь.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev, действительно.. Причем такая идея меня посещала, но я проверял просто во вкладке Инкогнито, ну и без авторизации естесстно.
Благодарю, мир Вам, девушку погрудастее и денег побольше.